# How do you pass variables into MongoDB via node-mongo-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to find a doc and set its sub object to 3.

```
{
  doc_id = 'dock_id1',
  update = events{a:{b:3}}
}
```

How do I pass this into a node-mongo-native query to set `events.a.b = 3` on the doc with the id `doc_id1`?

I don't mean setting `events.a.b` every time. I mean passing in a variable from that object in a way that I could get a new object with new data and apply it the same way.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give some more examples to illustrate what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass an object literal:

```
  collection.insert( { foo: 'bar' }, function( error, documents ) { console.log( 'error', error, 'documents', documents ) } );
```

.. or pass an existing object:

```
  var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
  collection.insert( obj, function( error, documents ) { console.log( 'error', error, 'documents', documents ) } );
```

If you're trying to create an object, this is not correct syntax:

> events{a:{b:3}}